# Google apps script - automatically filter the active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script which is intended to automatically filter the active sheet:

```
    function setFilter() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var filter = {};
      filter.range = {
        sheetId: tab.getActiveSheetId()
      };
    
      filter.criteria = {};
      // Which column to add the filter to
      var columnIndex = 0;
      filter['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
        'hiddenValues': ["✘"]
      };
      var request = {
        "setBasicFilter": {
          "filter": filter
        }
      };
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
    }
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a reference error mentioning that the tab isn't defined - what do I need to change? I have tried removing sheetID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Use [getActiveSheet](http://getActiveSheet()) to get the active sheet:
  `var tab = ss.getActiveSheet()`
- Then use [getSheetId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetId()) to get the id of the active sheet: `tab.getSheetId()`

### Solution:

```
 function setFilter() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var tab = ss.getActiveSheet(); // added code
      var filter = {};
      filter.range = {
        sheetId: tab.getSheetId() // modified code
      };
    
      filter.criteria = {};
      // Which column to add the filter to
      var columnIndex = 0;
      filter['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
        'hiddenValues': ["✘"]
      };
      var request = {
        "setBasicFilter": {
          "filter": filter
        }
      };
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
 }
```

I assume you are already aware of that, but in order for the code to work you need to enable `Google Sheets API` from the `Resources` tab in the old editor or `Services` in the new editor.